# how much should I worry about argument list too long?

Tags: bash

I have a shell script, which will use some * to do wildcard. For example:

```
mv /someplace/*.DAT /someotherplace
```

And

```
for file in /someplace/*.DAT
do 
  echo $file
done
```

Then when I think about error handling, I am worrying about the infamuse argument list too long error.

How much should I worry about it? Actually how long can the shell holds? For example, will it dies at 500 files or 1000 files? Does it depends on the length of the filenames?

**EDIT: 
I have found out the argument max is 131072 bytes. I am not looking for solution to overcome argument too long problem. What I really what to need is -- How long does it translate to normal string command? i.e : How "long" would that be the command? Does it count space?**

Comment: You have forgotten to enclose the `$file` in `""`. Better use `"$file"`.

Answer (score 4):

*pardon my ignorance*

<strike>If i remember correctly, is capped at 32Kb of data</strike>

first command

```
find /someplace -name '*.DAT' -print0 | xargs -r0 mv --target='/someotherplace'
```

second command

```
find /someplace -type f -name "*.DAT"
```

Comment: That command can be piped to `while read line` to perform a loop over every file, allowing you to replace the single (overflowable) `mv` command with a (safe) `mv` loop. (And, of course, this technique will work for any similar situation where a command might overflow like this.)

Comment: Using `read` to get files one at a time is not much different from `for`-looping over globs, but unlike glob for-loops, it's not even a safe way to parse filenames from stdin unless you are using a non-POSIX shell that supports using the null character as the `read` delimiter.  The `find -print0 | xargs -0` is much better b/c it is both safe and `xargs` will automatically split the argument list to keep it under the maximum length, resulting in fewer `mv` processes spawned and faster operation overall.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it depends on filename length. The command line maximum is a single hardcoded limit, so long filenames will exhaust it faster. And it's usually a kernel limitation, so there is no way around it within bash. And yes, this is serious: errors that occur only infrequently are always more serious than obvious errors, because quality assurance will probably miss them, and when they do happen it is almost guaranteed to be with a nightmarish unreadable command line that you can't even reconstruct properly!

For all these reasons: deal with the problem *now* rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

### Whether

How much should you worry about it? You may as well ask "What is the lifespan of my code?"

I would urge you to **always** worry about the argument list limit. This limit is set at compile time and can easily be different on different systems, shells, etc.. Do you know for sure that your code will always run in its original environment with expected input and that environment's original limit?

If the expansion of a glob could result in an unknown number of files **or** files with an unknown length being expanded **or** that expansion could exceed the limit that will be in effect in **any** unknown future environment then you should write your code from day one so as to avoid this bug.

### How

There are three `find`-based solution for this problem. The classic solution uses `xargs`

```
find ... | xargs command
```

`xargs` will execute `command` with as many matches as it can without overflowing the argument list, then repeat that invocation as necessary until there are no more results from `find`.

This solution is problematic because file names may contain newlines. If you're lucky you have a nicer version of find which supports null-terminating file names with `-print0` and you can use the safer solution

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 command
```

This is the same as the first `find` except it's safe for all legal file names.

Newer versions of `find` may support `-exec` with the `+` terminator, which allows for another solution

```
find ... -exec command {} +
```

This is functionally identical to the second `find` command above: safe for all file names, splits invocations of `command` into chunks that won't overflow the argument list. I prefer this form, when available.

Comment: My colleague told me he can mv 600 files without problem. So I am really wondering whether I need to care about such problem. 1000+ file is rare, 2000 files could be max.

Comment: @gunbuster363: The problem is that it's not a **number of files** it's a **number of bytes**. As Kilian Foth pointed out, files with longer names will cause fewer files to hit the limit sooner. If you always know that the total bytes of input will not exceed the argument list limit on the current and all future systems, by all means ignore the problem. Personally, I would rather have code which I know can't break in the future.